# Mobile browser is unable to load the XML data of Magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, soap-api-v2, .htaccess, apache2

I am new to magento. My question here is that I am unable to load the XML data in mobile browser but with the same link i am able to display the xml data in Desktop browser . Data is coming out of Magento's REST and SOAP api service

These are the two api access, being tried

http://new.sporteemail.com/api/rest/products and

http://new.sporteemail.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Resulting in redirect to http://new.sporteemail.com/mobiledirectoryhere/* only on mobile browser user agents.

and both these links are related product retrieving from the magento site with respect to REST and SOAP service of magento.

Is there a need to change my .htaccess file or Apache2 configuration

Here is the .htaccess file

### redirect for mobile user agents

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
```

Please help.

Comment: You're getting valid API output. Is this a Magento or Android question? If it's about Android other forums might work better. If it's Magento we're gonna need more specific info like errors and code to reproduce and help you debug

Comment: Sir i am getting the valid output in the desktop browser . But it will not run in android phone's browser ..Is there a need to modify in .htaccess file or magento admin panel